# In Finder and Terminal — can not delete a folder, (Error = "Directory not empty")

Tags: terminal, macos, acl, extended-attributes

Anytime I've run up against this in the past, I was always able to figure it out, and usually via the command line. I'll list all the commands I tried so far, followed by other things I've tried below that.

Commands I've tried so far, and were also ran as `root` using `sudo su root`:

- `rm -rf <folderName>`
- `rmdir <folderName>`
- `ls -@RelO` (shows folder is empty)
- `ls -Rail` (shows empty)
- `ls -ri` (shows empty)
- `xattr` (I finally removed the extended attributes of this folder, as `ls -la` showed an `@` at the end of the permissions.

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x@ 3 mike  staff      96 Jan 23 23:29 iPhoto Library
  ```

As mentioned, in addition to these Terminal commands, I...

1. Booted into Safe Mode (still says "Directory not empty")
2. Booted into Recovery Mode, then ran `csrutil disable` to turn off System Integrity Protection, and rebooted as normal. Then, from Terminal (again, via `sudo su root`), ran all of the same commands. It keeps saying "Directory not empty".
3. Booted into Single User mode, navigated to the folder, and ran the above commands (was sure this would work). It still reads, "Directory not empty"
4. Not copied, but moved this to a thumb drive (command key + drag to volume), a message read, "Was able to move folder, but can't delete existing one".

You may have noticed this is my old iPhoto Library file. Just so you know, I've finally (after many years) consolidated my newer "Photos" library, so I wanted to get rid of this, as it's almost 90 GB. And yes, I did 'right-click' to "Show Contents", then was able to get rid of everything inside of this folder, but can not get rid of the top-level folder.

I have never been stumped like this (I'm a Mac tech for 23 years). This is quite the forced feeding of some seriously humble pie.

Comment: The folder is not empty. The number of links is 3.

Comment: Have you tried fsck (or First-Aid in Disk Utility.app)?

Comment: Hi David - I saw that (3 links) in the long output (after running ls -@RelO), but then it never showed what they were (which it always does). I should also have clarified that it only give "Directory not empty" in Terminal. When I try this via Finder, it simply says, "File is in use". Finally - please pardon any breaches of protocol / etiquette - this was my first post to this (or any) Stackexchange forum. Not even sure if this is the right place to post this, but I can't find where to reply to your comments. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, try out `lsof +D [dirName]`

Comment: Hi Igor — Thanks... I just tried it... but nothing returns to the STOUT.

Comment: Also, I am correct in assuming that this is not the place I should be receiving replies, and likewise, replying myself? (I'm brand new here, and don't know where I'm supposed to answer... I've looked all over the page, but can't seem to figure it out. I mean, all other threads / questions... are answered in a forum format. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: @WharfCat Not actually, it’s better to comment if you have a guess but can’t really answer the question, or if you need more input from the topic starter. What about `lsof | grep [dirName]`? Though I think it is the same you might try it as well.

Comment: Hi Igor - Thanks for the response to both questions: (a) appropriate use of this forum, and (b) the question at hand, re: trying "lsof | [dirName]" -- I did try that as well, nothing appears in the stout in terminal... just the next line of command prompt (my username w/ #), and nothing.  But back to the correct usage of this forum - that's the thing - I AM the topic starter... and I've been expecting to see the 'Reply' text box / field... with other people's responses. The only thing I see is this "comments" field. Thanks.

Comment: But one more thing: In the Finder, the error is "File is in use"... but when trying this via Terminal, the error / response is, "Directory not empty". Google searches for both of these, have yielded nothing that's worked so far. I feel like after 22 years as a Mac tech, I've finally met my match!! (I can NOT figure this out), and am resisting the whole "nuke and pave" (backup, reformat, reinstall) solution, because this *should* be doable, via the command line.

Comment: @WharfCat, try to boot into single user mode (restart && `CMD+S`) and `/sbin/fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk1`. Also can try to delete folder form there mounting filesystem in read-write mode. Could you also post `ls -lhdO "iPhoto Library"` and `ls -lhOa "iPhoto Library/"`? Also try emptying the Trash by `rm -ri ~/.Trash/*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi David and Igor — Issue is resolved, but the solution is not something I'd have considered as even being a relevant one, but I wanted to post it here for whoever this might help in the future (as well as put closure to Igor's / Dave's possible curiosity. And once again, thank you guys for all your suggestions.

For a completely different (separate) reason, I logged out of iCloud (on the Mac — not iPhone or iPad). Went through all the usual items (saved my stuff locally), etc., and somehow - when I logged back in, my trash was empty!

One of the things I wanted to share here with this forum / group, is that I learned something I hadn't known previously: Since the incarnation of iCloud, the PATH to my "Trash" folder no longer is (what it's *always* been)... /Users/myHomeDir/.Trash — instead, it was now: myHomeDir$ /Users/mike/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/.Trash/  — and I only learned this after searching that first path several times, both while logged in as myself (in Terminal), but also, while booted into Single User mode. *Nowhere* in either of those means, was my Trash directory located. But when I drag and dropped that  from my trash... to my terminal - that was the path it gave. (and confirmed this while logged into Single User).

Go figure... sorry for the lengthy post, but wanted to be thorough in my resolution for anybody this might help. But all this said, I guess that since the advent of iCloud, this is now the default location for everybody's Trash folder? This presents an entire new thread of questions for me (Apple's implementation of their folder hierarchy, since iCloud) - but no questions specifically at the moment.